# How to make Save/Load system in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I'm making a game but I don't know how to make it savable. By savable I mean I would like to be able to put a save and load button in the game so you can save it and close it and if you open it again You can load back to where you were.

Comment: A save game is just a file that you know what goes in and how to read it. Presumably, libgdx being made with Java, one can assume that it can write and read files. Now it's just a matter of deciding what you put in that file. What issue are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: I just don't know anything about it

Comment: About what? Perhaps [libGDX's documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) could help get you started?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the `Preferences` interface for that.
Here is an example:

```
//This will get your preferences from storage
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("myprefs");

//If the preference key is empty, create it by putting a value into it
if(!prefs.contains("key")) prefs.putInteger("key", "1337");

//Get value from a preference key "key" (must not be empty)
int val = prefs.getInteger("key"); 

//Do something with your value and put it back to the preference
val+=something;
prefs.putInteger("key", val);

//This will finally save the changes to storage
prefs.flush();
```

This works equivalent for other data types like float, String, boolean, ...

For reference, take a look at [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences). It will help you a lot

Comment: This is a link-only answer. The Stack Exchange standard is that a question "answer" should actually contain an answer.